# MySQL - Знаки вопроса вместо (SET NAME не помогает)

Tags: mysql

Всем привет!

Создал базу данных на MySQL, но он не воспринимает русские буквы. Даже простой
 SELECT 'пиу-пиу' FROM dual показывает "???-???".

Пробовал всякие SET NAMES  'cp1251' - не помогает.

Что делать?

Comment: *Даже простой SELECT 'пиу-пиу' FROM dual показывает "???-???".* Что, даже в окне mysql.exe ?

Comment: "Пробовал всякие SET NAMES 'cp1251' - не помогает."

Просто не надо работать с кодировкой ср1251, работайте с utf8. Приведите всё к одно кодировке. Начиная от кодировки файла и заканчивая кодировкой поля таблицы.